# Why is Minecraft not updating?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I updated my Xbox recently, and I got version 1.14.60 of Minecraft: Bedrock Edition. I checked my updates so I could get version 1.15 / 1.16, and it wasn't there.
Is the Nether Update not on Xbox? Or is my Xbox being weird?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1.14.60 is currently the latest (production release) version of the Bedrock Edition**, and was released on April 15, 2020.
[Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_version_history) is a list of all versions of Minecraft Bedrock.

**The full Nether Update (version 1.16) has yet to be released for both [Java](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.16) and [Bedrock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.16.0) editions** (see [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Update)). No release date has been given.

The [Nether Update is available as beta release](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/the-bedrock-nether-update-beta-here-), however, which was released on March 16, 2020. You can follow [this link](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/signin?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ffeedback.minecraft.net%2Fhc%2Fen-us%2Farticles%2F360004438671-How-to-Join-and-leave-the-Minecraft-Beta) to sign up for the beta.
This corresponds with [version 1.16.0.51](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_beta_1.16.0.51).

Answer (score 0):

The Nether Update is not yet available for Bedrock edition.

Comment: Ah, my brain not working. The usual.